# How to find quantile in Scala with approxQuantile method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi how's it going? I'm getting extremely weird results when calling the approxQuantile method on a numerical column...

```
  val quantile_ninety = df.stat.approxQuantile(Array("distance"), Array(0.9), 0.2)
```

produces...

```
[[D@4bca8eaf
```

as an output. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The version of [approxQuantile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameStatFunctions.html#approxQuantile(cols:Array%5BString%5D,probabilities:Array%5BDouble%5D,relativeError:Double):Array%5BArray%5BDouble%5D%5D) that you are using has the return type `Array[Array[Double]]`.

To print this table you could use this code:

```scala
quantile_ninety.foreach( a => {a.foreach( b => print(b + " ")); println})
```

For your example code you would get a single number, a table of size 1 by 1.